# UIImageview Fade

Tags: xcode, uiimageview, fade

I am trying to get my image to fade out and fade in with when i click on my button. Is there something wrong with this code? My image stays visible when I click on my button.

```
- (IBAction)Alpha:(id)sender {
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseIn];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:2];
    _image.alpha = 1;
    [UIView commitAnimations];
    [UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(animationDidStop:finished:context:)];
  }
-(void)animationDidStop:(NSString *)animationID finished:(NSNumber *)finished context:(void *)context {
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:2];
    _image.alpha = 0;
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the methods on UIVIew, the class, not on your instance of the UIImageView that you want to fade.

You'll want something like

```
[self.myImageView beginAnimations....
```